# ggplot2 re-order Stacked Plot

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataframe with data in the following format.

```
Category_Name, State, Percent
B            , Accepted, 20
B            , Declined, 80
A            , Accepted, 10
B            , Declined, 90
```

I want it to plot it such that the order of category name is dependent upon Percent where there state is Accepted from largest to smallest.

So far I have

```
jr.states$category_name <- factor(jr.states$category_name, levels = sort(levels(jr.states$percent[state == "accepted"])))


jr.states %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=category_name, y = percent * 100, fill = factor(state)), order=-percent) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x ="Category", y ="Percent", title = "Accept/Decline/Ignore Rates by Category")
```

But I'm getting the error

```
Error in levels(jr.states$percent[state == "accepted"]) : 
  object 'state' not found
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `State` seems to have a capital S in your dataframe

Comment: If `state` is in `jr.states`, you need `[jr.states$state == "accepted"]`